# How do I complete the "Not a Scratch" challenge?

Tags: destiny-2

This Deep Stone Crypt raid challenge seems pretty tough in that we have to preserve ALL the sparrows from each heat bubble to the end -- is there a cheese or easier way to complete this challenge to get the exotic Sparrow?

Comment: Commenting as I'm not 100% sure it works yet and have yet to try; but my team intends to attempt the challenge by leaving the pikes at the beginning, completing it with our sparrows, and then using the transmats at each bubble to send ourselves back to the start where we can more safely drive the pikes to each bubble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My team completed this tonight. We used a cheese, so up to you if you want to use it.

If you place a pike outside the heat bubble when you have frostbite debuff, then get onto it from inside the bubble. You are protected from the frost permanently and can slowly sparrow your way to the end.

*Update, This cheese has been fixed now*

Also worth noting that when a Pike is destroyed it will respawn either at the start or nearby. So be sure to check the first spawn, then Sparrow the route to pickup the Pike again along the route. You can use the Fallen teleporters in each heat bubble to teleport back a bubble.

Here is the route.

[image: Pike route]

Comment: You can actually bring all the sparrows to the end solo, but you still need all 6 players to sit on them for the triumph to trigger.